# How to keep two related files in sync?

Tags: c, makefile

Suppose I have a Makefile containing something similar to this:

```
program.revision: smaug
    git rev-parse HEAD > program.revision

program: $(obj)
    $(CC) -o $@ $^ $(LDFLAGS)
```

The aim is hopefully clear: I want `program.revision` to **always** mirror the revision of the source that created `program`.

But I wrote that and then realized it likely does not adequately cover my needs nor concerns:

1. If the compile of `program` fails half-way, is the old (working) version of `program` left behind, or is it deleted?
2. Related to point 1, how do I make sure that if `program` was deleted, `program.revision` is deleted as well? And similarly, if the old build survives, that the old `program.revision` remains intact?
3. How do I make sure `program.revision` is always in sync, even if I specifically execute `make program` as opposed to a plain `make`?
4. I realize this problem could be made considerably simpler by deleting old files prior to building them, but it is very important to minimize the chance that `program` ends up missing due to a failed build.

How do I properly handle this situation?

Edit:

After writing this, I suddenly realized my problem might not be what I think it is. My aim is to have a build of `program` know the revision it was created with, so maybe the answer isn't in a `Makefile` and `program.revision` file, but instead in finding a way to compile this information into the executable. Hmm..

Comment: Indeed. If you want to know what revision built a binary then embed that into the binary. A common way to do that (for C programs) is with a `VERSION` (or similar define) passed on the compilation line `-DVERSION=$revision` or similar.

Comment: As to some of your other questions the [Errors in Recipes](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Errors) section of the GNU Make Manual is likely going to be of some use here.

Comment: Add `program.revision` as a prerequisite of the `program` target and it will always be run if necessary.

Comment: Do you want `program.revision` to mirror the revision of *the source?* Or do you want it to mirror revision of `program` (as indicated by your point 2)?

Comment: To expand on what Etan said with `-DVERSION=$(revision)`.. you can also do something like `#include "program.revision"` in your C file. Either change the output to produce a meaningful C declaration, or include it in such a way (e.g. `const int VERSION = `<newline>`#include "program.revision"`<newline>`;` )

Comment: Beta: I want(ed) it to mirror the version of the source used to create the executable. mtijanic: That's an interesting approach, I'll keep it in mind for the future.